# How to forward a type alias of a template class in another namespace

Tags: c++, c++11, type-alias

I have a type alias as

```
using A = ns::B<int>;
```

And want to class forward it in another file. How to do it?

I tried the following. It works, but looks ugly

```
namesapce ns { template<class> class B; }
using A = ns::B<int>;
```

Any more perfect way?